# Arrays between classes?

Tags: java, arraylist

Main Class;

```
package finalapp;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author bassammetwally
 */
public class FinalApp {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Team tem = new Team();
        Tournament tour = new Tournament();
        System.out.print("Whats the tournament name?\n");
        tour.setTourName(input.next());
        System.out.print("Please enter the tournamen date\n");
        tour.setTourDate(input.next());
        System.out.print("Please enter the location\n");
        tour.setLocation(input.next());
        System.out.print("Please enter number of Software Stations\n");
        tour.setAvaliableHardwareIns(input.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Please enter number of Hardware Stations\n");
        tour.setAvaliableHardwareIns(input.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Please enter number of field testing");
        tour.setAvaliableFieldTesting(input.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Please enter max number of teams\n");
        tour.setMaxNumberOfTeams(input.nextInt());
        tour.tourStatSet(1);

        while (true)
        {
            int choice;
            choice = input.nextInt();
            if (choice == 1)
            {
                System.out.printf("Enter Team %s Names\n",tour.getMaxNumberOfTeams());
                for (int i = 0; i >= tour.getMaxNumberOfTeams();i++)
                {
                    System.out.print("Please Enter Team Name");
                    tour.addingTeam(input.next());
                    tem.teamStats(1);
                    tem.teamJudgeStat(1);
                    Have a PREPARING team turn the robot on 
                    (set the robot status to READY) to prepare for inspections        
                }
            }
            else if ( choice == 2)
            {
               System.out.print("Sending prepareing teams");
               //for (int a = 0; a >= tour.getTeamsChecked(); a++)
               {

               }

            }
    }


}
```

Question:

I'm making a robot contest simulation, and I'm trying to get the main class to:

- Add teams, which I already did
- Change status of each team in the array

But my main idea was to go through the `ArrayList` and change the variables in the other classes, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you could, please cut down on the amount of code you link so that only the code MOST relevant to your question is shown. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

From what it sounds like you should be able to use simple getters and setters to do what you want.

Simply have a method that sets the value you want into an array, and another that gets the array or a specific index in the array. This way you can set and share the array between classes.

Comment: but if have more than 10 teams, won't it easy to have a method that takes the team names and adds it to the ArrayList in the other class? @MoH.

Comment: You could have a method that you pass a team array list into that would automatically add that array list into your other class's array list